# Unexpected output from to_string(int)

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to count the length of an int that may or may not have leading 0s. For instance 0100. I tried using the to_string() method and it turned 0100 into the string "64" for some reason & I don't understand why. I am relatively new to C++ and I think I may have fundamentally misunderstood how to_string() works.

I am using C++11 for my compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By starting your integer literal with 0, you actually declared the number in **octal** base. (100 in octal = 64 in decimal)

See [cppreference's page on integer literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal) for more details.